# Asp.net database migration, what's the Down method for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, database-migration

When I add-migration, Up and Down method are generated.

and I know when I update database (update-database), it runs the Up method.

How about Down method?

when it will run, is it for rollback? and, how can I run it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its for when you want to "downgrade" the database to a previous migration state.  You use it with the `-TargetMigration` flag of the `Update-Database` command.  For example, if you have added the following migrations:

- Initial
- FirstMigration
- SecondMigration (current state)

You can revert the database to the Initial migration state by:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:Initial
```

In which case the code in the `Down()` methods of the `SecondMigration` and `FirstMigration` classes will run.